# How to avoid repeated creation Jquery wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to avoid using `$("#check1")` second time in below statement?

```
$("#check1").prop("checked",!$("#check1").prop("checked"));
```

By any trick can I do something like below?

```
$("#check1").prop("checked",!this.prop("checked"));
```

Comment: How about `var c = $("#check1"); c.prop("checked", !c.prop("checked"));` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a function as a callback you'll get the current value.

```
$("#check1").prop("checked", function(i, value) {
    return !value;
});
```

`.prop( propertyName, function(index, oldPropertyValue) )`

- `propertyNameThe name of the property to set.`
- `function(index, oldPropertyValue) A function returning the value to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old property value as arguments. Within the function, the keyword this refers to the current element.`

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var el = $("#check1");

el.prop("checked",!el.prop("checked"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $check = $("#check1");
$check.prop( "checked", !$check.prop("checked") );
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use *this* but by this way:

```
$("#check1").prop("checked",!$(this).prop("checked"));
```

Comment: But the value of `this` depends on where the above is run from. For ex: if from inside another click handler, `this` will refer to the element that was clicked and not the checkbox.

Comment: @techfoobar Do looking at the statement, abstractly, as it regarded in the question makes my answer wrong?

Comment: Kind of, because your answer cannot be directly applied to an app as it comes with the precondition of `this` being equal to the checkbox itself, which need not always be the case. Your answer is correct, but only if fired from within an event handler bound to the checkbox, for ex.